# centering print result from a form in php

Tags: html

I have this code which I'm trying to get it centered on the page but its not working. I'm not sure where to put the  tag or call a css to center the result from this print. When I add the css id="center" to , it centers the form as well but I want to center only output of the print. Please help.

```
 <p class="name">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="
      <?php if (isset($_POST['fname'])){
           print htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']); } ?>"/>
  <label for="name">Name&nbsp;<img src="nfonin/req.png" /></label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of a tag you desire to use.

If you plan on using a

tag then you might want to center the div either within the tag or in a linked class file.

```
<p style="text-align: center">Content here"</p>
```

If you want the it aligned in a container on the page you can use A `<div>` tag which will create a container that will resize to the content and can be centered both itself and the text within. If you desire to have this you can use

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align:center;">Content here"</div>
```

The margin-left and margin-right being set to auto makes sure that the content is centered and the container becomes the size of the content making margins large enough on either side to make it centered.

you can also put this into a linked css file using:

```
<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the header of the page and:

```
#yourid {
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

within the css file and any `<p>` or `<div>` tag you give the id `yourid` will have those properties. Unfortunatley as far as I know `<p>` tags aren't affected by margin adjustments. I hope this helps.